# Laurent expansion of inverse of quadratic matrix polynomial

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, inverse, laurent-series

Let $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices of the same size where $A$ is invertible and the kernel of $B$ is $1$-dimensional. Consider the function $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb M$ defined by $$f(z) = z^2I + Az+B.$$ I use $\mathbb M$ to denote the space of square matrices in which $A$ and $B$ live and write $I\in\mathbb M$ for the identity matrix.  I am interested in the behavior of $f^{-1}(z) = f(z)^{-1}$ around $z=0$. I suspect that $f^{-1}$ around $z=0$ has the form $$\sum_{n=-1}^\infty a_n z^n.$$ Could someone help me with calculating such expansion?

I would like the coefficients as explicitly as possible. The standard trick of partial fraction decomposition and using $$(I-X)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty X^n$$ does not work as it is not clear that we are able to factor $f(z)$.

---

**Example:**
(As requested by Rodrigo.) Suppose that $\mathbb M$ consist of $2\times 2$ matrices. Then take $A = 2I$ and $B=\text{diag}(1,0)$. I want to look at the inverse of
$$
f(z) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
z^2 + 2z+1 & 0 \\
0 & z^2 +2z
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is given by
$$
\frac{1}{\det(f(z))} \begin{pmatrix}
z^2+2z & 0 \\
0 & z^2+2z+1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $\det(f(z)) = z(z^2+2z+1)(z+2)$. We then clearly see that $f(z)$ splits up in a part that is analytic at $z=0$ and a part that is not
$$
f(z)^{-1} = \frac{1}{(z^2+2z+1)(z+2)}\begin{pmatrix}
z+2 & 0 \\
0 & z+2
\end{pmatrix}
+
\frac 1 {\det(f(z))}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now I see that if I want to know the behavior of $f(z)^{-1}$ around $z=0$, I just need to consider the Laurent expansion of a `normal' rational function $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ that I can calculate.

Comment: Your edits are fine! Thanks. We may assume that $A$ and $B$ have real entries, but I don't think that matters.... As for $\mathbb M$, I view it as a vector space over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Since the output is a matrix, I would use the same notation used for matrices — $F$ rather than $f$.

Comment: Please provide an example, say, for $A = 2 I$ and $B = \mbox{diag}(1,0)$.

Comment: Do you really need the determinant? It is a diagonal matrix, after all. So, you have a diagonal matrix of rational functions. However, these rational functions do not have the same poles. How would a Laurent-like expansion look like in this case?

Comment: What do you mean? To get the Laurent expansion in the example we calculate the expansion of each rational function and put the coefficients in the matrix. That way we get $f(z)^{-1} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty C_n z^n$ where $C_n$ are matrices. In this example the expressions are simple enough to do that by hand, but I don't see how that helps the general case?

Comment: For the general case, you may have to use the Smith normal form or something like that.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer. But I'm interested in the behavior of $f(z)^{-1}$ around $z=0$, that is why I compute the Laurent series around $z=0$.

Comment: Well you get terms of the form $\frac 1 z$, so $f(0)^{-1}$ is not defined if that is what you mean?

Comment: I happens. I don't think that the smith normal form will do me any good. I believe such normal forms are about integral matrices. My guess right now is that we may write the adjunct $\text{adj}(z^2I+Az+B) = p(z)$ where $p$ is a polynomial with matrix coefficients of degree $2(n-1)$ if $n$ is the dimension of the matrices. This way we have something like $(z^2I + Az+b)^{-1} = \frac 1{\text{det}} p(z)$. Maybe it is possible to say something about the coefficients of $p$?

Comment: My impression is that the Smith normal form is about rings — of integers, of polynomials, etc. This sort of thing may be covered in [Antsaklis & Michel](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/0-8176-4435-0). Try to take the example farther.

Comment: Oh I see, there are versions for general PIDs. I just know the one for integral matrices. I will look at your book. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider providing the background and motivation for this question. It is easier to answer when the question is a story in itself.